# How to retrieve all embedded document value using the official C# driver for MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Given the the following classes and sample document, How do I retrieve a AnswerChoice document from the Question collection where _id in AnswerChoice is '4d6d336ae0f84c23bc1fae00' using the official C# driver.  Thank you.

```
public class Question
{
     [BsonId]
     public ObjectId QuestionId
     {get;set;}

     public string Question
     {get;set;}

     public List<AnswerChoice> AnswerChoices
     {get;set;}
}

public class AnswerChoice
{
     [BsonId]
     public ObjectId AnswerChoiceId
     {get;set;}

     public string Answer
     {get;set;}

     public int Order
     {get;set;}

}
```

// Sample document

```
{
  "_id": "4d6d3369e0f84c23bc1facf7",
  "Question": "Question 1",
  "AnswerChoices": [
    {
      "_id": "4d6d3369e0f84c23bc1facf2",
      "Answer": "Answer Choice A",
      "Order": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": "4d6d3369e0f84c23bc1facf3",
      "Answer": "Answer Choice B",
      "Order": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": "4d6d3369e0f84c23bc1facf4",
      "Answer": "Answer Choice C",
      "Order": 3
    },
    {
      "_id": "4d6d3369e0f84c23bc1facf5",
      "Answer": "Answer Choice D",
      "Order": 4
    },
    {
      "_id": "4d6d3369e0f84c23bc1facf6",
      "Answer": "Answer Choice E",
      "Order": 5
    }
}
```

//Code to retrieve Question that have AnswerChoice with _id of "4d6d336ae0f84c23bc1fae00"

```
List<Question> list = new List<Question>();
MongoServer _server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost");
MongoDatabase _database = _server.GetDatabase("test");
var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("AnswerChoices._id", new ObjectId("4d6d336ae0f84c23bc1fae00")));
MongoCollection<Question> collection = _database.GetCollection<Question>("Question");
MongoCursor<Question> cursor = collection.Find(query);

foreach (var q in cursor)
{
    list.Add(q);
}
```

//How do I retrieve an AnswerChoice object with _id of "4d6d336ae0f84c23bc1fae00" ?????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should load question(as in code above) and use linq or foreach to get answer item with specified _id. So code will looks like:

```
List<Question> list = new List<Question>();
MongoServer _server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost");
MongoDatabase _database = _server.GetDatabase("test");
var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("AnswerChoices._id", new ObjectId("4d6d336ae0f84c23bc1fae00")));
MongoCollection<Question> collection = _database.GetCollection<Question>("Question");
MongoCursor<Question> cursor = collection.Find(query);

var id = new ObjectId("4d6d336ae0f84c23bc1fae00");
foreach (var q in cursor)
{
    var answerChoice = q.AnswerChoices.Single(x=> x.AnswerChoiceId == id);
    list.Add(q);
}
```

Also i suggest instead of Find use FindOne method(because i suppose that you sure that only one answer with above specified _id exists).

Comment: Is there a way to do it directly without using linq?  I suppose your way would work with what I need.  I'm just curious.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you only want the subdocument as opposed to the entire document. This is not currently supported in Mongodb. On a match, the entire document is returned. Your query is similar to [Filtering embedded documents in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138454/filtering-embedded-documents-in-mongodb).
There is an open JIRA item for this feature request which you should vote on http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-828