# How to get a specific embedded document inside a MongoDB collection with Java Driver?

Tags: java, mongodb

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043965/how-to-get-a-specific-embedded-document-inside-a-mongodb-collection) but I am using Java Driver.

This is a document from my collection:

```
{
    "_id": "7",
    "servers": [
       {
          "ip_port": "127.0.0.1:8081",
          "name": "server1"
       },
       {
          "ip_port": "127.0.0.1:8082",
          "name": "server2"
       }
    ]
}
```

After the query I want to get a document like this:

```
{
    "ip_port": "127.0.0.1:8081"
}
```

I have tried to translate the instructions of the second answer of the linked question in Java and the result was this:

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = db.getCollection("collection")
        .find(and(eq("_id", "7"),
                eq("servers.name", "server1")))
        .projection(Projections.fields(Projections.elemMatch("servers"), Projections.excludeId()))
        .iterator();
```

but if I execute this query and I print `cursor.next().toJson()` this is what I get:

```
{ "server" : [{ "ip_port" : "127.0.0.1:8081", "name" : "server1" }] }
```

So how can I get a specific embedded document inside Mongo DB with Java Driver?