# MongoDB query into an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongojs

I have the following schema into my DB:

```
{ name: 'AFG',
  documents: [
    { name: 'doc1',
      templates: [
        { name: 'templ1',
          lastModified: <Date>},
        ...]
    },
    ...]
}
```

I am trying to make a query to look for the template with name 'templ1'. If I find it, I have to compare the last modification date with another and update the value. If I don't find it, I have to push it into the array.

I have tried to do it with the following query:

```
Country.findOne({name : countrySelected, documents : {$elemMatch: {name: documentSelected}}, 'documents.templates' : {$elemMatch: {name: templateSelected}}}, function(err, templateFound){...}
```

But I get the following error:

```
MongoError: cannot use the part (documents of documents.templates) to traverse the element ({documents: [ { name: "Passport", templates: [] }, { name: "Visa", templates: [] }, { name: "Driver's Licence", templates: [] }, { name: "Id Card", templates: [] }, { name: "Other", templates: [] } ]})
```

Someone knows how can I do it? Thanks!!

Comment: Please check a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043965/how-to-get-a-specific-embedded-document-inside-a-mongodb-collection

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `$in` operator to search in arrays.

```
Country.findOne({
    name : countrySelected, 
    documents: {
        $elemMatch: {
            $and: [{
                name: {
                    $in: documentSelected //<-- must be array like ['doc1']
                }
            }, {
                'templates.name': {
                    $in: documentSelected //<-- must be array like ['tmpl1']
                 }
            }]
        }
    }
}, function(err, templateFound){
    //do something with err and templateFound
});
```

To update the LastModified date you need to update it in the callback function and save the document.

[See this answer for nested array updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573117/updating-nested-arrays-in-mongodb-via-mongo-shell#18574314)