# MongoDb find by value in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

here is the model of my collection :

```
classes:[{
            class:String,
            info:{
                    subjects:[String],
                    students:[{
                        name:String,
                        surname:String,
                        matriculae:Number,
                        path_1:String,
                        path_2:String
                    }],
                    classTeacher:{
                        name:String,
                        surname:String
                    }                   
                }
            }],
    accademicYear:String}];
```

I'd like to retrive value 'matriculae' given the name,surname and accademicYear of a student. I cant wrap my head 'round it tho! Thanks for help.

Comment: Let us know what you have tried

Comment: Show what you have tried .. till now ..

Comment: I was trying something like : db.collections.find({accademicYear:'value',classes:{info:{students:{$elemMatch:{name:'value}}}});

Comment: but fact is i have no clue how to move

Comment: Can you add a sample document from your collection ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want the result flat format, try this:

```
 School.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: '$classes'
    }, {
        $project: {
            accademicYear: 1,
            students: "$classes.info.students"
        }
    }, {
        $unwind: "$students"
    }, {
        $project: {
            accademicYear: 1,
            matriculae: "$students.matriculae",
            name: "$students.name",
            surname: "$students.surname",
        }
    }
    ])
```

In case of the classes is collection and accademicYear is inside of the classes collection.Plus added the match criteria.

```
db.getCollection('classes').aggregate([{
    $project: {
        accademicYear: 1,
        students: "$info.students"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$students"
}, {
    $project: {
        accademicYear: 1,
        matriculae: "$students.matriculae",
        name: "$students.name",
        surname: "$students.surname",
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        name: name,
        surname: surname,
        accademicYear: year

    }

}])
```

Comment: school beeing the collections name?

Comment: Yeah. Classes is subarray of school collection. In your case classes is a collection?

Comment: classes is a collection, tho with the code above all the students from that document are returned. Formatted according to the last projection. I'd like to be returned just the one students that matches the criteria (name:value, surname:value) inside the document classes that matches (accademicYear: value) of the whole collections

Comment: If so, your model is wrong. "academicYear" and "classes" are the same level of the model. If "classes" field is the collection, academicYear has to be inside of the model. Please fix your model first. The second question you can add $match field into aggregation method. I can add it after you fix the model.

Comment: Sorry for ignoring your efforts, i was busy. I'll see if something's wrong with the model. But i've read on another question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043965/how-to-get-a-specific-embedded-document-inside-a-mongodb-collection) that it is not possible to retrive a field from a specific document, the full document is returned. I've worked around it by simply iterating over the results on the server, looking for a match on the result and picking the field i wanted.

Comment: Yes, you can retrieve specific field using aggregation method, but yes it's not possible with the only find method. Try my last edited answer. You will be able to retrieve documents you want.