# To query and project dictionary values that are array elements in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, projection

I am new to MongoDB and need help with projecting an array element when another array element is found.

Below is an example of my document-

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5bab53afcfbc7829bc6356a0"), 
  "category": [
    {
      "categoryRating": 3,
      "categoryName": "Crime",
      "categoryNameNew": "Crime"
    },
    {
      "categoryRating": 4,
      "categoryName": "Security Services",
      "categoryNameNew": "Other"
    },
    {
      "categoryRating": 4,
      "categoryName": "Civil Unrest",
      "categoryNameNew": "Societal"
    },
    {
      "categoryRating": 4,
      "categoryName": "Terrorism",
      "categoryNameNew": "Terrorism"
    },
    {
      "categoryRating": 3,
      "categoryName": "Kidnapping",
      "categoryNameNew": "Terrorism"
    },
    {
      "categoryRating": 4,
      "categoryName": "Geopolitical",
      "categoryNameNew": "Geopolitical"
    }
  ], 
  "country": "Setif", 
  "apiSource": "iJET", 
  "overallScore": 4, 
  "newDate": "2017-12-28T19:52:58Z"
}
```

I want the `categoryRating` value when I specify that `categoryName` is "Crime". So, in this case, I need it to print `categoryrating` as 3.

So far, I have tried the following query-

```
 db.RiskScore.find({"country":"Setif","category.categoryName":"Crime"},{"category.categoryRating":1})
```

The following is the result of my query-

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5bab53afcfbc7829bc6356a0"),
  "category": [
    { "categoryRating": 3 },
    { "categoryRating": 4 },
    { "categoryRating": 4 },
    { "categoryRating": 4 },
    { "categoryRating": 3 },
    { "categoryRating": 4 }
  ]
}
```

It returns all the categoryRatings instead of just that where the categoryName is Crime. Please, any help with respect to this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a specific embedded document inside a MongoDB collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043965/how-to-get-a-specific-embedded-document-inside-a-mongodb-collection)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You're just missing the [positional $ operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) in the projection:

```
db.RiskScore.find({"country":"Setif","category.categoryName":"Crime"},{"category.$.categoryRating":1})
```

Comment: Thank you.. This returns { "_id" : ObjectId("5bab53afcfbc7829bc6356a0"), "category" : [ { "categoryRating" : 3, "categoryName" : "Crime", "categoryNameNew" : "Crime" } ] } and solves the problem.

Comment: Also, Is there a way only the categoryRating field can be obtained?

Comment: Yes, through the aggregation framework. I would suggest to do it on the client side if your document is so small. Otherwise, please update your question with the exact definition of what you would want the output to look like and I'll get you sorted.