# How do I ask mongo for all the embedded documents that match my criteria?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a collection of movies, and the movie collection has an embedded document array of reviews. I want to select all the reviews with status=1

```
{
  reviews: [
    {
      status: 0,
      text: 'hello'
    }, {
      status: 1,
      text: 'hi'
    }
}, {
    ... etc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an answer to the same question: [Filtering embedded documents in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138454/filtering-embedded-documents-in-mongodb)

In current stable version of mongodb it's still no way to do embedded document filtering.

In 2.1.0 there is aggregation. You can filter reviews using [unwind](http://wiki.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework+-+$unwind) and [match](http://wiki.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework+-+%24match)

Not tried myself, though.