# Mongo - request all embedded comments in Post query

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm adapting the Microscope tutorial to my needs and am having difficulty writing a query which gathers all the comments embedded within a post.

Here is my query so far:
     `Posts.find({"postId": this._id}, {"comments":{}});`

Here is an example post I want to get the comments from:

```
{
"_id": "Ad9RYqWqbsJKZx3h7",
  "title": "Writing decimal number words as a decimal number",
  "userId": "9yqTaFeQSqvKmNn8B",
  "author": "Sacha Greif",
  "submitted": "2017-01-05T03:26:18.908Z",
  "commentsCount": 4,
  "comments": [
{
  "body": "Hello",
  "postId": "Ad9RYqWqbsJKZx3h7",
  "userId": "73qGvsRuqNtXcaZDx",
  "author": "student",
  "submitted": "2017-01-05T10:26:45.745Z"
},
{
  "body": "How are you?",
  "postId": "Ad9RYqWqbsJKZx3h7",
  "userId": "73qGvsRuqNtXcaZDx",
  "author": "student",
  "submitted": "2017-01-05T10:28:17.225Z"
}
  ]}
```

It seems to return a cursor, but I am not able to use the `toArray()` function on it.

I have read this is not possible ([Filtering embedded documents in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138454/filtering-embedded-documents-in-mongodb)), but this was six years ago...

I've also seen posts about `$slice` and `aggregate` but can't seem to get me head around them.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Are you subscribing to the data? Why not simply use `PostsfindOne(postId)` and extract all of the comments from the received object?

Comment: The data is published: `Meteor.publish('comments', function(postId) {
  check(postId, String);
  return Posts.find({postId: postId});
});` and here is the subscription in router.js `Router.route('/posts/:_id', {
  name: 'postPage',
  waitOn: function() {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('singlePost', this.params._id),
      Meteor.subscribe('comments', this.params._id)
    ];
  },
  data: function() { return Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }
});`

Comment: How would I go about extracting the comments from the received object? Something like: `var post = Posts.findOne({postId: this._id});
   var commentList = post.comments.toArray(); return commentsList;`?

Thanks MasterAM.

Comment: In the publication, you need to query by _id, not postId.

Comment: I added autopublish in case this was the issue. Still no luck though...

Comment: Have you tried querying `Posts.findOne(this._id);`? If you have and get no results, please **edit your question** to include all of the relevant code for reproducing this. No need to call `toArray()` of whatever, as the `comments` property is already an array.

Answer (score 0):

query this->
Posts.find({"comments.postId": this._id});

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use `findOne` to get the specific document from the collection and you can use `forEach` Loop to iterate through the comments array of that document.

```
var post = Posts.findOne({_id: "<id_of_the_post>"});

var post_comments = post.comments; // post_comments contains the comments array
```

or if you want to do something with each comment use forEach

```
    post_comments.forEach(function(entry, index, arr){
    // entry has the comment object 
//do something with the comment
    });
```

I hope this helps.